# Rococo testnet Parachain is not Producing Blocks?

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, rococo, block-production, test-network

I'm trying to connect to rococo testnet as a parachain using own customized parachain !

**It works locally and produces blocks when connected to local Relay chain**

But when connected to Rococo it doesn't produce blocks. It was first registered as parathread but now it is connect temporarily as a parachain using issue request for rococo parachain slot !

Below it the process that I followed

=> I'm using custom accounts for validotors (collators) generated through subkey ! (same for local relaychain)

=> Following commands I used

`./target/release/Honey-protocol \ --collator \ --force-authoring \ --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \ --base-path /tmp/parachain/Node1 \ --port 40333 \ --rpc-port 8844 \ -- \ --execution wasm \ --chain ../polkadot-sdk/raw-local-chainspec.json \ --port 30343 \ --rpc-port 9977`

**Adding Custom Keys**

`curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["aura", "0xd6e89b6e99dcec6d5134dd6a1a16aae1b79f7c70f48ef6406b97982aae62fe28", "0x962f3b79ee06d4ef463588f239de314b42c88e8966369bd388d5e28c9c3d6111"],"id":1 }' http://127.0.0.1:9022`

`curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["gran", "0xd6e89b6e99dcec6d5134dd6a1a16aae1b79f7c70f48ef6406b97982aee62fe28", "0xcb85350e64d79c592fdbcea9adf63f694be0a8f7dd66c7572df8fc47ba18c2fc"],"id":1 }' http://127.0.0.1:9022`

**Second Collator**

`./target/release/Honey-protocol \ --collator \ --force-authoring \ --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \ --base-path /tmp/parachain/Node2 \ --port 40334 \ --rpc-port 9023 \ --bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/40333/p2p/12D3KooWKRCTF4tWQ6xmA5YWMqs6Mb9eYkApBBxM7fS31UsVJ41F  \ -- \ --execution wasm \ --chain rococo \ --port 30344 \ --rpc-port 9978`

**Adding Custom Keys**

`curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["aura", "0x560763e9ae1ea8bb9d38f8a2c6b8788548fc95028f6ede890c44ffed3315e062", "0x96e144d9c66bed23c35651646778d7ab31783347e4c213d45727854adfe82905"],"id":1 }' http://127.0.0.1:9023`

`curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["gran", "0x560763e9ae1ea8bb9d38f8a2c6b8788548ff95028e6ede890c44ffed3315e062", "0x3556b1a562eb3837f520147879abfc26461f8cf06c83bec895bd1a8e26dcb712"],"id":1 }' http://127.0.0.1:9023` 
**Both Nodes Running **

[image]

**Registered as a Parachain On Rococo Testnet as 4302**

[image]

**Attached is Plain Chain Specs used**
[plainChainSpec.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17-kG5oDeg20vDBi3rO25BJurqO47GVAz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems like your node is still busy syncing with rococo

Comment: how long it's gonna take to sync ? is this depends on machine processing power or the network speed ? @DaanvanderPlas

Comment: How long it's gonna take to sync @DaanvanderPlas?