# Rococo testnet Parachain is not peering and Producing Blocks

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, rococo

I found [similar](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10147/rococo-testnet-parachain-is-not-producing-blocks) questions but it doesn't help me. I am struggling to peers two node and produce block. Everything works fine in rococo-local, Below is the process that I followed,

**collator-node01**

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node --collator \
  --force-authoring \
  --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \             
  --port 50333 \
  --rpc-port 8855 \
  -- \
  --execution wasm \
  --chain rococo \
  --port 50343 \
  --rpc-port 9988
```

**collator-node01-keys**

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain % ls /tmp/node01/chains/dev_rococo_testnet/keystore
61757261f6b199de5d8a16b958cb619723106f9ffc26c0c24d8e12e5689676d3b8cf3345 
6772616ef72f5e6c3bdc8735f7ff92855ed6d316d7beea938ddee81fc070a55ac075db9a
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain %
```

[node01_logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUBlq_2XKQa6GGycLz6pIR3G6_DrCFfT/view?usp=drive_link)

**collator-node02**

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node --collator \
  --force-authoring \
  --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \             
  --port 50334 \
  --rpc-port 8856 \
  -- \
  --execution wasm \
  --chain rococo \
  --port 50344 \
  --rpc-port 9989
```

**collator-node02-keys**

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain % ls /tmp/node02/chains/dev_rococo_testnet/keystore
6175726192a8bc80c2d3a1dad385c5e9dee9e38ee72b9576296a2815c131c166b2cc381a
6772616ed0e5832d9fddfdc16491ec11a13047cc4c00f48802c0fe32eec0ffe85b5ca3af
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain %
```

[node02_logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yiCWY8pDRqHOSN3FLFr1lUNFHmb0L5hy/view?usp=drive_link)

[raw-chainspec_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18tNsV-g_487xqT7P2uremDyyL_9ww4ae/view?usp=drive_link)

I am using *Macbook AirM1 and brave browser*

**While running collator node I get this issue in logs terminal. Could that be the cause of this issue?**

```
2023-11-17 08:53:01 [Parachain] ⚠️ The hardware does not meet the minimal requirements for role 'Authority'.
```

Comment: Did you get a slot on Rococo?

Comment: yes `4,323` is my rococo slots @AurevoirXavier

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments in the similar question you pointed is that you always have to waiting until your collator finish the syncing.
If you want a faster sync you can use the flag `--sync fast` (See more here [What's the fastest way to sync a node only keeping full state for the last N blocks?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8864/whats-the-fastest-way-to-sync-a-node-only-keeping-full-state-for-the-last-n-blo) ).

If the parachain is still not producing blocks but not showing any error messages, you need to try to figure out why, usually is due to small issue with the onboarding as a parachain.

The following checklist should help avoiding the most common reasons why a parachain won't produce blocks:
[Our parachain doesn't produce blocks [checklist]](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/our-parachain-doesnt-produce-blocks-checklist/1395#1395) and for more check this guide I am creating: [Troubleshooting: Common Collator Issues](https://hackmd.io/zqbmc38LQnyfBmLWtkXrrg)